# IPython notebook cannot load files with cython code

Tags: python, ipython, cython

My IPython notebook works fine yesterday then today for some reason it cannot load files with Cython code in it. I got the following warning:

> WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET
>   /static/components/codemirror/mode/text/x-cython/ text/x-cython.js

After waiting for 5 or 10 minutes, IPython notebook usually collapses.

Anyone knows what caused this problem? I tried other files. As long as the files don't have Cython code in it, they can be loaded without any problem.

Really appreciate it if anyone can help.

Comment: Try to show some minimal code which will reproduce the behavior, give the version of ipython and cython you use, and what changed between today and yesterday, did you install new stuff ?

Comment: It's trying to find a codemirror mode for Cython, to do syntax highlighting. What version of IPython are you using? It may be a bug.

Comment: http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html#using-the-ipython-notebook  talks about a  `cythonmagic` extension.

Comment: Now I found out what caused the issue. I ran a simulation with a huge amount of output, and I printed out some of the output in the cell of the Ipython notebook. The output made the notebook file so large that it takes forever for Ipython to load. Thanks for jeanrjc's hint.